# Sharepoint Foundation search filter? (Exclude all but SP wiki 'x')

Tags: search, sharepoint-foundation, filter, wiki

I've looked (unsuccessfully) for what others have done on this topic.

Within our Sharepoint Foundation site we have multiple wikis and we'd like to use the Search feature to search content from only a single particular wiki and not the rest of the site.

Is there an existing SP Foundations feature I should be using?

Everthing I'm seeing that comes close appears to be a custom .NET webpart, or part of SP Enterprise.

There must be something I'm overlooking that might appear obvious to others.

Feel free to point it out.  I'll be glad to be sheepish if it's something should have known.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into Search Scopes? You should be able to make a scope based on the location of the content in a custom Content Source -- your wiki site.

You can create a webpart page with search webparts that are specific to a scope of your choosing.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee792872.aspx

Comment: I havent worked much on Foundation so I didn't provide the option of Search Scopes. Just wanted to confirm with you , is search scopes part of Foundation License.

Comment: My apologies, search scopes aren't for SharePoint Foundation.

Comment: @Moss Farmer and Mike.  Thx for asking the clarification.
Appreciate your question and Mikes follow-up that Search Scopes isn't included w/Foundation.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply go to advanced settings for every wiki library and uncheck the option "Allow items from this document library to appear in search results " . This way only the Wikis that you need to appear in the search results will get indexed.

Comment: Thx.  I'd seen that approach, but we want all content indexed.  Other teams will still want to search their content using a filter for their relevant content..  (Yes I believe I know what that suggests about our design of the sites.  But we're stuck w/them given budget cuts and 25% I.T. staff reductions.)

Comment: In that case could you kindly update your question with a little more detail concerning the site structure and the user groups so that we can have a better understanding of the problem statement and suggest you a solution accordingly.